# How do I Filter array from two columns to non-null pairs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

With the code below, I have a Google Sheet, and I'm trying to create arrays from different sections.

```
function onFormSubmitTest(e) {
    //Open spreadsheet based on URL
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('sheetnamehere');
    //Set as Active
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
    //Set Tabs as Variables
    var Rsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emailer");
    var Lsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Unique Databases");

    //----Set last Rows as Variables----
    // Gets Values from different sections
    var formResponses = Rsheet.getRange("N3:N").getValues();
    var databaseNames = Lsheet.getRange("A2:B").getValues();
    var developerNames = Lsheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues();

    // Filters to ranges that have values, ignores null
    var lastRvalues = formResponses.filter(String);
    var lastLvalues = databaseNames.filter(String);
    var lastDvalues = developerNames.filter(String);

    // Sorts arrays for faster indexing
    var lastR = lastRvalues.sort();
    var lastL = lastLvalues.sort();
    var lastD = lastDvalues.sort();

    // Unique Databases
    var currentDatabases = lastL;

    // Current Developers
    var currentDevelopers = lastD
```

On the Unique Databases tab, I have 100 rows on the sheet, with only 28 of them having data. If I have the code below, I can see it only has 28 values as expected:

```
var databaseNames = Lsheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
```

However, when I add the other column, I get 100 values, with the vast majority being ["", ""]. Should note that the 28 values are key>value pair, so if there's a value in A:A, there will be one in B:B. If null in A:A, then B:B is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try Lsheet.getRange("A2:B" + Lsheet.getLastRow()).  Naturally, if you define the range to be the entire B column, it will return all values in each cell, regardless of whether it's an empty string or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `[["", ""], ["", ""]].filter(String)` returns the entire array. To see why, replace `filter` by `map`:

```
[["", ""], ["", ""]].map(String)  //  [",", ","]
```

Those are truthy strings, with a comma.

A correct way to filter text by nonemptiness of the first column of the range would be

```
range.getValues().filter(function(row) {return row[0]})
```

(The usual caveat about 0 value being falsy applies, but it doesn't look like you would encounter numeric 0 there, the column being text. And the string "0" is truthy.)

(Also, "null" is not the right term here, Apps Script returns empty strings "" for empty cells, which is different from `null`)

Comment: Thanks, @If! Putting 'getValues().filter(function(row) {return row[0]})' after the range filtered out the strings, perfectly. Does this also apply to ranges of any size, that based off of the index in the []?

Comment: Yes. For any range `getValues` returns a double array like `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`. When you apply `filter` to it, the filtering function will get a row as its argument, for example `[1, 2, 3]`. So you have to decide what element of the row to look at, and what the criterion should be. `row[0]` means filtering based on the 1st column of the range. `row[2]` would be the 3rd column.